# Expected length of sum of vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, expected-value

> Suppose we have $n$ arbitrary unit vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots, v_n$. (Here, a "random" unit vector is defined as $\langle \cos(x), \sin(x) \rangle$ for a random $x$ such that $0 \leq x < 2 \pi$). Evaluate the **expected value** of $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i\right|$$ where $|v|$ denotes the magnitude of $v$.

---

For $1$ vector, the answer is trivially $1$.

For $2$ vectors, we could fix $v_1$ to the $x$ axis, and the answer would be

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sqrt{\left(1+\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{2}+\sin\left(x\right)^{2}}\right)dx$$

First, let us evaluate the numerator.
$$\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sqrt{\left(1+\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{2}+\sin\left(x\right)^{2}}\right)dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(x\right)}\right)dx \\
&=2\cdot\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\left(x\right)}{2}}\right)dx \\
&=2\cdot\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|\right)dx \\
&=2\cdot\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)dx \\
&=4\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-4\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
&=8 \end{align}$$

Then, our answer for $2$ vectors would be $\frac{8}{2\pi} = \frac{4}{\pi}$.

For $3$ vectors, we have

$$\frac{1}{4\pi^{2}} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sqrt{\left(1+\cos\left(x\right)+\cos\left(y\right)\right)^{2}+\left(\sin\left(x\right)+\sin\left(y\right)\right)^{2}}\right)dx\ dy$$

This seems hard to understand, does it have an elementary answer or a way of approaching?

Comment: I think this is a paper from 1955 that answers this question! 
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-26/issue-2/The-Distribution-of-Length-and-Components-of-the-Sum-of/10.1214/aoms/1177728540.full

Comment: Which magnitude? Vectors where?

Comment: You want to find an expected value but provide no details on the PDF.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo They want Euclidean norm and the vectors are in the plane and their distribution is uniform on the unit circle. The question implicitly assumes they are independent as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem seems to be posed by Pearson in 1905 to challenge the crowd (in the journal of Nature)
https://www.nature.com/articles/072294b0

The distribution of length is solved subsequently by J.C. Kluyver in 1905. (that document cannot be found in google...though many cited it  "a local probability problem").

A paper that discussed it more thoroughly is [On the Problem of Random Flights](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/41133753.pdf?casa_token=nfOjAwxhWBMAAAAA:mQniA-keNIflQXNcjRZzrAh3v9Zr4S_3EUifC5sATs-VFRkPQthio5Yy8vJouc-p6l-hOCL7plnrU7komL6uiK-rGuRyDwwttSLG1I5gvCtO76yNPZWv) in 1985. From what I read, the exact solution of the distrubtion of length is an integral of product of Bessel function, which could be numerically evaluated but may not be simplified..
[image]

Comment: Now, in order to find the expected value of the magnitude, we need to solve for r so that this function is equal to 1/2, right?

Comment: I think what you described is the **median** magnitude. For the expected (**mean**) length, we need to differentiate this $Pr(|S_n|\leq r)$ by $r$ and then multiply $r$ and do integral over $r$ (from $0$ to $n$)

Comment: Hmm, in this case, can we get elementary forms for low n?

Comment: So you care more about small n scenario than large n asymptotics? For large n, we can use the limit of random walk ..

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious to see if there are any closed form given n.

Answer (score 3):

This is such a wonderful and thought provoking question. I have an idea on how we may be able to solve it in an elementary way.

I have an idea on how we can estimate the **average** magnitude for any number of vectors using a recursive method. Now, we know that for the case of one vector ($n=1$) the average magnitude  will be equal to $1$. For $n=2,$ it is the following case;

[image: 2-Case]

In this case you found the average as $\frac{4}{\pi}$ by letting
$$v_1=\binom{1}{0},$$
and integrating the magnitude of the vector $v_1+v_2$ with respect to the angle between the two vectors, and finally dividing it by $2\pi$ to get the average length of $v_1+v_2$ as the angle between them varies in $[0,2\pi).$

Now, for the $3$ vector case, we have $3$ vectors $v_1,v_2,$ and $v_3$ and we need to find the average magnitude of $v_1+v_2+v_3.$

WLOG, we let $v_1=\binom{1}{0}$ and we will vary the angles of the other three vectors (since they are unit vectors we know their magnitude). Here's a picture;
[image: 3-Case]

Lets only focus on the angle between the vectors $BC$ and $CD$ for a while. We know that the angle between them ranges from $0$ to $2\pi,$ so the magnitude of the vector $v_2+v_3=BD$ is also some number. But the average magnitude of $v_2+v_3=BD$ has to be $\frac{4}{\pi}$ as you earlier calculated in the $3$-vector case.

So, since we are considering an 'average' scenario, we can say that the magnitude of $BD=v_2+v_3$ is $\frac{4}{\pi}.$ But we need to be very careful. We are considering a superposition of all the possible angles between $v_2$ and $v_3.$

[image: 3]

So we have just two vectors now! One is $v_1=\frac{1}{0}$ and the other is $v_2+v_3,$ where the second vector has a magnitude of $\frac{4}{\pi}.$ Now, we need to consider the angle between the two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2+v_3$ to range from $0$ to $2\pi$ and take the integral of the total vector magnitude for a given angle $\theta.$ Just like in the first case with two vectors.

Similarly, we can continue in a similar way to get a sequence of average vector magnitudes from for any number of vectors. Hope this works for you.

Comment: This divide and conquer strategy is really clever! like it.

Comment: Does this actually work even if v_2+v_3 isn't distributed linearly?

Comment: But then $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{4}{\pi} \cdot \cos\left(x\right)\right)^{2}+\frac{4}{\pi} \cdot \sin^{2}\left(x\right)}\ dx$ should be equal to $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(\frac{4}{\pi}+\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{2}+\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}\ dx$ right? As it does not matter if we do $v_1 + v_2$ and $v_3$, or $v_1$ and $v_2+v_3$

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this doesn't quite work, as it assumes an incorrect distribution on the sum of two vectors; the operation in question isn't linear.

Comment: I also doubt this approach, because we are integrating over different 'types' of variables. But then, we can also set the integrations constants differently to get the correct answers. I'm still trying to understand this approach, and will correct it if it turns out wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Binxu's comment on his post, although this isn't really an answer—just seeing how the result applies. For $n$ unit vectors, we have

$$F(n;r)=\Pr (|S_n|\leq r)=r\int_0^\infty J_1(rt)[J_0(t)]^n\, dt.$$

You can think of this probability function as the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the result. The probability density function (PDF) $f$ can be recovered by differentiation, and then the expected value found by its definition as the first moment around zero. To wit,

\begin{align*}
f(n;r) &= \partial_r F \\
&= \frac{1}{r} F(n;r)+r\partial_r\int_0^\infty J_1(rt)[J_0(t)]^n\, dt. \\
E_n &= \int_0^n f(n; r)\cdot r\, dr \\
&= \int_0^n F(n; r)\,dr+\int_0^nr^2\partial_r\int_0^\infty J_1(rt)[J_0(t)]^n\, dt\, dr.
\end{align*}

The second integral can be dealt with using integration by parts:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^nr^2\partial_r\int_0^\infty J_1(rt)[J_0(t)]^n\, dt\, dr &= r^2\left.\int_0^\infty J_1(rt)[J_0(t)]^n\, dt\right]^{r=n}_{r=0}-\int_0^n2F(n; r)\, dr.\\
\end{align*}

Thus we get

\begin{align*}
E_n=n^2\int_0^\infty J_1(nt)[J_0(t)]^n\, dt-\int_0^n F(n; r).
\end{align*}

For $n=2$ WolframAlpha gives $2$ for the first term and $2-\frac{4}{\pi}$ for the second one, so $E_2=\frac{4}{\pi}$. As to how the latter is derived... no clue. I am ignorant of the many identities and integrals involving Bessel functions. For $n=3$ WA fails to find the second integral. Personally I doubt there is a nice closed form. But at least now it's a double integral regardless of $n$....

Hopefully someone will have an actual answer.

Comment: Great to see your simplification and that you actually tried this with mathematica! Didn't get the time to try this